# I can't change the TextSwitcher font

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/uibackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/intoscript"
        android:text="Gift Finder"
        android:textColor="@color/CityLights"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/kisiSecimLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lettersforlearners"
            android:text="&lt;"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textSwitcher"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
            android:text=">"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here, i have to change the TextSwitcher font. When i first run this app on my real phone, i didn't get that problem. But after that, i deleted whole app and created it again. And now i have the font problem. I can't remember how i did it first time. Is there a way to see an app's codes which is I run on my real phone? Or do you know how to change TextSwitcher font?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `font family` attribute for each child `TextView`.

```
<TextSwitcher . . .>
    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="..."
        . . . />

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="..."
        . . . />

</TextSwitcher>
```

Then the TextSwitcher will alternate between the TextView children, with the use of font family (Typeface) that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextSwitcher txtSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
txtSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
    public View makeView() {
        TextView txtView = new TextView(Activity.this);

        Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.font_name);
        txtView.setTypeface(typeface);                 
                
        return txtView;
    }
});
```